The satisifes keyword fails to detect excess properties after assignment
The satisfies keyword catches excess properties when assigning a value.  After that, however, it no longer complains when the same extra keys remain present.  Why is that?
interface MyType {
    num: number,
}

const largeData = {
    num: 1,
    str: "", // TS2353: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'str' does not exist in type 'MyType'.
} satisfies MyType

largeData satisfies MyType // Expected an error, but received none

It does detect missing properties both during and after assignment:
interface MyTypeExtended {
    num: number,
    str: string,
}

const smallData = {
    num: 1,
} satisfies MyTypeExtended  // TS1360: Type '{ num: number; }' does not satisfy the expected type 'MyTypeExtended'.

smallData satisfies MyTypeExtended // TS1360: Type '{ num: number; }' does not satisfy the expected type 'MyTypeExtended'.

You can imagine a situation where I might wish to be alerted that I need to clean this data:
function ReturnMyTypeOnly(input: MyTypeExtended): MyType {
    return input satisfies MyType // Expected an error, but received none
}

Playground with example code

This isn't specific to satisfies. Excess property checking only occurs for object literals. See linked questions/answers above for more information.
